# $f(x)$ is continuous and smooth enough and domain is $x>0$, moreover $f(x)<f(\frac{x}{2})$, then is $f^{\prime}(x)\leq 0$?

Tags: functions

The function $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable and domain is $x>0$. Moreover, $f(x)\in (0,1)$. If $f(x)<f(\frac{x}{2})$ holds for any $x>0$. I think $f(x)$ should be a decreasing function, i.e. $f^{\prime}(x)\leq 0$ should hold, but I do not know how to prove it ?

I meet this problem when I try to prove another conclusion. Please help to prove my conjecture.

Comment: Yes, $f(x)$ is smooth enough, i just added this condition.

Comment: My previous answer was wrong, but I have an intuition that this is not true. I am thinking of another example

Comment: Thank you. Intuitively, I think this is right. It would be excellent if you can come up with one example.

Comment: Does $f(x)\in (0,1)$ hold for *all* $x > 0$?

Comment: yes, it holds for all $x>0$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(x)=\sin x-\frac12x$. For this function we have $g(x)<g(x-2\pi)$ and yet it is not decreasing.
Also let $h(x)=\frac12 +\frac1\pi \arctan x$, which is a strictly increasing map $\Bbb R\to (0,1)$.
Now let $f(x)=h(g(c\ln x))$ with $c=\frac{2\pi}{\ln2}$. Then $f$ is not decreasing and yet $$f(\tfrac x2)=h(g(c \ln x-c\ln2))=h(g(c\ln x-2\pi))<h(g(c\ln x))=f(x)$$
[image]

Comment: Thank you, nice work, man!

Comment: But $f$ does not satisfy the condition $f(x)\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Just rescale it and you're done

Comment: @H.Potter: It is not immediately obvious to me how you would rescale $f$, because $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$. Perhaps I am overlooking something simple?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah that's true, I didn't read carefully the example. But, well, now you understood why it's not possible ? It's always possible to have a counter example where $f$ oscillates on $[\frac12,1]$ as long as the minimum of $f$ on $[\frac12,1]$ is greater than the maximum of $f$ on $[0,\frac12]$

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I totally overread that part of the conditions.